# Is it allowed to follow the imam at the same time

Tags: salat, masjid, prayer-timings, imam-al-jamaah

I see alot of people praying in the mosque in congregation, they always go into rukoo' at the same time of the imam when he is about to say *Allaahu akbar*, but then, they go into rukoo' when he is about to say the first part *Allaa-* or do whatever he is about to do, and i feel like this is wrong, even though he they should go after he finishes saying it and ***goes first*** is it allowed to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to this and other similar hadith:

Imams has to be **followed**:

> *Narrated Anas bin Malik:*
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) fell down from a horse and his right
> side was either injured or scratched, so we went to inquire about his
> health. The time for the prayer became due and he offered the prayer
> while sitting and we prayed while standing. He said, "The Imam is to
> be followed; so if he says Takbir, you should also say Takbir, and if
> he bows you should also bow; and when he lifts his head you should
> also do the same and if he says: Sami`a l-lahu liman hamidah (Allah
> hears whoever sends his praises to Him) you should say: Rabbana
> walakal-Hamd (O our Lord! All the praises are for You.")
> **Sahih Al-Bukhari USC-MSA web (English) ref. Vol. 2, Book 20, Hadith 215**

The word **follow** means **going after** not going *besides* he or she.